# How to tell if the Flowplayer has stopped counting

Tags: javascript, flowplayer

I'm working on a player using Flowplayer. With this player there could be some switching of the video stream coming in to the player with a change in video format and bitrate.

The problem now is that when there is a change in the video stream the video in the player stops and just freezes.

Is there any way in JavaScript to determine if the counter for the Flowplayer has stopped? And if so, is there also a reload command JUST for the Flowplayer?

Answer (score 0):

have you looked at `getState()` in their [API docs](http://flash.flowplayer.org/documentation/api/player.html)?

getState() - integer - Returns the state of the player. Possible values are:

- -1: unloaded
- 0: loaded
- 1: unstarted
- 2: buffering
- 3: playing
- 4: paused
- 5: ended

  also getStatus() will help you determine the current time of the video.